# How record video in flutter_webrtc?

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, flutter-webrtc

I am using flutter_webrtc package to view the live video streaming from a cctv camera in mobile. There is a requirement for a feature in which the user can record the live video in the app. So, how to implement this feature using flutter_webrtc? Or is there any other methods available?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code it is mentioned in [web_rtc](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/main/example/lib/src/capture_frame_sample.dart) example

```
void _captureFrame() async {
    final stream =
        await RTCFactoryNative.instance.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      'audio': false, // if you want audio pass true
      'video': true,
    });

    final track = stream.getVideoTracks().first;
    final buffer = await track.captureFrame();

    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());

    setState(() {
      _data = buffer.asUint8List();
    });
  }
```

Comment: This code is for capturing a single frame right?

Comment: Yes this code is capturing single frame but you can modify according to your need with it's documentation and example.